# Magento 2.3 URL_KEY bug , but if i saved product its ok

Tags: magento2.3

I'm having a strange problem with magento related to my url key on products

I explain to you :

- I import my products via CSV (Pimgento), everything is good. (Photo, Description, Name etc ...)

But for the url keys of my products I have an empty field:

[image]

But if I click on 'Save the product' (without any changes), the url key appears!

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea why such a bug?

You would have a solution? Or a module that can make a save of all my products?

Thank you for your time & help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not importing the url_key field from the CSV. Can you please post headers of your CSV with one record. Magento create URL automatically on save when url key field is empty. It creates URL according to product name with "-" (hyphen) separation.